# How to link alternative spare parts

Tags: sql, inventory

There is a database with spare parts for some machinery in a factory. Within the spares listed, there are some parts that could be alternatives to each other. For example, let's say on machine A there is a bolt 1 which can be used in machine B in place of bolt 2.

How can we link the alternative spares and through which SQL statement could list all possible alternatives to a specific spare part?

Comment: use left join for alternative but will return 1 part with many rows for alternate... but if you'd like to see new columns for alternative then use Pivot

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Question refers to the intial design stage. Only thinking of implementing a link table, in addition to the spare parts table, such as: Bolt1 to Bolt2, Bolt2 to Bolt3, Bolt2 to Bolt4, and when asking for alternates of Bolt 1 to have as result Bolt2, Bolt3, Bolt4

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Create additional table(s) with list of alternatives. Original_part_id / alt_part_id. Maybe some rating or other coefficient for quality+price for quick choice of alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after of the design then below should suffice

```
| machine_master_table |
machine_id
machine_name
....

|machine_parts_table
id
machine_id
parts_id


| master_parts_table |   -- all parts are listed here.
parts_id
parts_name
parts_type
size
blah...


| alternate_parts_table |   -- this table will link all your main part and alternates
id    -- identity seeded
main_parts_id
alts_parts_id
date_effective  -- if you want to keep historical alternate
end_date
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what if the alternate_parts_table has been filed with bridge connections, like i.e. 1->2, 2->3, 3->4. What query could give me the 4 as alternate of 1?

Comment: will be a CTE to get parent and child relationship for alternates.

Comment: is there any way to "save" the results for each part, i.e. using a trigger every time we update/insert/delete a spare part connection? Thinking to speed up the query time in case of a huge, large scale machine_parts_table.

Comment: i don;'t get your question

Comment: instead of running CTE each time on a specific part, i.e. Bolt1, wonder if it is possible to run the CTE in the background when a connection entry in the alternate_parts_table has been made, in order to have the results immediately when needed and without running a new CTE.

Comment: CTE will run first (create a hierarchy) without the reference of the machine then you join the result to the machine and main part, in most cases CTE are relatively fast

Comment: You have just made my day!